# if $f(x) = 0$ everywhere except on a closed subset of measure zero, then $\int_Q f$ exists and $\int_Q f = 0$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : Q \to R$ be a bounded function over rectangle $Q$. Show that if $f(x) = 0$ everywhere except on a closed subset of measure zero, then $\int_Q f$ exists and $\int_Q f = 0$.

Require some Hints in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: What does "measure zero" mean?

Hint 2: Recall the definition of an integral, with partitions and upper and lower sums.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of a set of measure zero, what it says about a cover of the set. Hint: it says something about it being arbitrarily small. Now consider how you compute integrals with partitions. For showing that the integral is zero, show that you can partition the rectangle such that the upper and lower sums over the set $X$, of measure zero, can be made arbitrarily small, which will give you the result